# Windows xp error while backup files

Tags: backup, windows-xp

I have a usb external hard disk of size 400GB which I'll be using for backup on windows and ubuntu machines. On windows xp when I try to backup huge files(vbox VDIs in GBs) from the drive E:/ to the external HD, it is giving disk full error, but the external HD has left 370GB of free space. What would be the problem and how could I resolve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your drive is formated to fat32, convert that to ntfs an you should be fine.
and this should be on superuser.com :)